# Performing IIF on a Double value in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, double, expression, ssrs-2012, iif

I currently have a column in my report that is calculating an Average:

```
=FORMAT(Avg(Fields!intGradeTransposeValue.Value),"#.#")
```

I am currently trying to use the result of that calculation to then perform an IIF statement, but I am getting an error:

> The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox20.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' contains an error: [BC30311] Value of Type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel.ReportItem' cannot be converted to 'Double'

My expressions is:

```
=CDbl(IIF(ReportItems!Textbox6 <= 1.4, "A*", 
        IIF(ReportItems!Textbox6 <= 2.4 AND >= 1.5, "A",
            IIF(ReportItems!Textbox6 <= 3.4 AND >= 2.5, "B",
                IIF(ReportItems!Textbox6 <= 4.4 AND >= 3.5, "C",
                    IIF(ReportItems!Textbox6 <= 5.4 AND >= 4.5, "D"
                        IIF(ReportItems!Textbox6 <= 6.4 AND >= 5.5, "E"
                            IIF(ReportItems!Textbox6 <= 7.4 AND >= 6.5, "U", "Error"))))))))
```

How can I do the calculation I need?

ADDITIONAL

I have added below where the error is coming - this is confusing me as it seems to be accepting the first double of 1.4. I am using the suggested answer below, but this is also not working.

[image: Double Issue]

Comment: I am pretty sure you are saying cast the output which would be string value of A* or B etc as double. Which gives the error cannot cast to double. You would probably want to wrap the reportItems sections in the CDbl() instead like: `CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6)` to cast that number only to compare it against your static double values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error you are receiving, the issue is that you are attempting to convert the `ReportItems!Textbox6` itself to a double, not the value within it.  In order to reference the value of the Textbox, you'll need to reference it as `ReportItems!Textbox6.Value`.  So I believe the answer you'll need will combine arahman's answer with this change:

```
=IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 1.4, "A*", 
    IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 2.4 AND >= 1.5, "A",
        IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 3.4 AND >= 2.5, "B",
            IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 4.4 AND >= 3.5, "C",
                IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 5.4 AND >= 4.5, "D"
                    IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 6.4 AND >= 5.5, "E"
                        IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 7.4 AND >= 6.5, "U", "Error")))))))
```

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/built-in-collections-reportitems-collection-references-report-builder?view=sql-server-2017)

Based on the edit to the original post, I missed the other issue with the expression.  You can't compare the values like that.  You'll need to add additional references to the Textbox value after the `AND`.

```
=IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 1.4, "A*", 
    IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 2.4 AND CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) >= 1.5, "A",
        IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 3.4 AND CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) >= 2.5, "B",
            IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 4.4 AND CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) >= 3.5, "C",
                IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 5.4 AND CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) >= 4.5, "D",
                    IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 6.4 AND CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) >= 5.5, "E",
                        IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 7.4 AND CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) >= 6.5, "U", "Error")))))))
```

Comment: Sadly, as you can see from my edit on my question, this is also not working. I have resorted to exporting to Excel and performing the calculations there.

Comment: I've edited my answer.  The new expression should work?

Comment: An additional note, you may also need to enclose each comparison in parentheses like `(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 2.4) AND (CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) >= 1.5)`

Comment: So so close. The final line is coming up with an error. I have added in a closing parenthesis after "U" which has reduced the error slightly, but I can't work out why it is having issues:
 IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) <= 7.4 AND CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6.Value) >= 6.5, "U") "Error")))))))

Comment: Hmmm... the closing parenthesis before the "Error" shouldn't be necessary as each `IIF` takes three parameters and the "Error" would be the third parameter for the last `IIF`.  Actually, it looks like you're missing a couple of commas, now that I take a closer look.  Add a comma after "D" and after "E" and see if that solves it.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you are saying cast the output which would be string value of A* or B etc as double. Which gives the error cannot cast to double.

You would probably want to wrap the reportItems sections in the CDbl() instead to cast that number and then compare it against your static double values.

You would only cast the field this way if it really needed to be changed to a double for comparison.

```
=IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6) <= 1.4, "A*", 
    IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6) <= 2.4 AND >= 1.5, "A",
        IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6) <= 3.4 AND >= 2.5, "B",
            IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6) <= 4.4 AND >= 3.5, "C",
                IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6) <= 5.4 AND >= 4.5, "D"
                    IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6) <= 6.4 AND >= 5.5, "E"
                        IIF(CDbl(ReportItems!Textbox6) <= 7.4 AND >= 6.5, "U", "Error")))))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this and it does not work. It still does not like the Double value.

Comment: @MIS_Gem What does that value of the TextBox6 look like originally and then what does it look like after you did the format(value, "#.#")

Comment: @MIS_Gem why don't you make sure the values in the query are decimal and then when the average is gathered they are already as doubles when you do the comparison expression. So no need for the extra FORMAT() inside the ssrs field.

Comment: The original data of intGradeTransposeValue.Value is a integer, but when it is performing the average the result is a double as the averages won't all be whole numbers, but I believe it is stored as Text (not sure how to check this). I need to convert that value into a Grade. I was wondering if there was a way to do all this in one go rather than using ReportItems! So add to the original expression where I calculate the average?

Comment: I usually do not use AVG() as sometimes it can get confused and not use the correct fields you would use manually. I usually go for the method of get the grades and get the amount of people or whatever your other variable is. Then, in the ssrs field you can do `gradesamount/countofpeople = AVGGradeOverall`. Or in the case of 1 persons average grade from all tests, you could do: `TotalOfAllGradesNumber/NumberOfTests = AVGGradeForThatPerson`. In the query if I needed them to be a double overall I would cast to float or decimal in the query each field.